# Why the following program prints 1 instead of what I enter as input?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I recently came up with this assignment  that has the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int i;
  printf("%d", scanf("%d",&i));
}
```

Comment: Because scanf returns successful reading inputs, in this case 1

Comment: Don´t use `void main()`!  Use `int main()`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio better, `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [man page for `scanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf),

> "These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure."

So, it returns the **number of items** successfully matched and stored (**not** the value it scanned), which in your case, happens to be 1. Then, `printf()` prints that value.

That said, for a hosted environment, `void main()` should at least be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because scanf on successful execution returns 1.
If you want to print 'i' do this

#include 
void main()
{
     int i;
     scanf("%d",&i)
     printf("%d",i);
}

Comment: "On successful execution returns 1" in this case yes but your statement is misleading. You should read the @Sourav Ghosh answer